Databricks Runtime 13.3 - how can I use Databricks Connect without Unity Catalog?
The official documentation for Databricks Connect states that, for Databricks Runtime versions 13.0 and above, my cluster needs to have Unity Catalog enabled for me to use Databricks Connect, and use a Databricks cluster through an IDE like PyCharm. However, the situation I have at hand is the following - my cluster uses Databricks Runtime 13.3, and Python 3.10.12, and it does not have Unity Catalog enabled. This configuration will not change soon, so I am stuck.
How do I use Databricks Connect with the cards I was dealt?

If UC is not supported in the current version, try using ODBC/JDBC server to connect to your server

@Aswin That definitely would work for Spark SQL. But that won't be able to handle PySpark's DataFrame methods, right?

I'm running into other issues but supposedly setting data_security_mode to NONE should disable the unity catalog requirement.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/admin/clusters/policy-definition#--supported-attributes
